# Console shows correctly-formatted JSON, but JsonObject is unable to parse it

Tags: c#, .net, json, uwp

I am connecting to an external API, that (given the parameters), prints a result set in JSON. The objective is to convert this JSON into readable values and add them to an object array. It's a UWP app, so some of the older libraries that I found on the internet were not available any more. The following is the code block that fetches the JSON and then attempts to parse it:

```
private void beginWork()
{
    string feed_data = getFeed().Replace(@"\", "").Trim(new char[1] { '"' });
    Debug.WriteLine(feed_data); // <-- THIS PRINTS OUT THE CORRECTLY FORMATTED JSON WITHOUT ANY ESCAPE CHARACTERS
    JsonObject obj = JsonObject.Parse(feed_data); // <-- THROWS AN "INVALID JSON ERROR HERE" AND VALUE OF VARIABLE IN AUTOS SHOWS JSON DATA WITH ESCAPE CHARACTERS AND ADDITIONAL QUOTATION MARKS BEFORE AND AFTER THE STRING
}

private string getFeed()
{
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    string url = "URL HERE";
    HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
   return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
}
```

So what's going wrong here? When the `Debug.WriteLine(feed_data);` line executed, I see valid JSON in the output console, but still get the parse error.

---

**Edit: Sample JSON (expected and the one that shows in console):**

`[{"id":"884","author":"795","title":"The sum of ages of 5 children born at the intervals of 3 years each is 50 years. What is the age of the youngest child?","details":" ","datetime":"1439099443","answered":"1","vote":"0","answers":[{"id":"884","author":"788","answer":"4 years","datetime":"1439165670","votes":"0"}]}]`

**vs the JSON in Autos window and what the parsing fails on:**

`"[{\"id\":\"884\",\"author\":\"795\",\"title\":\"The sum of ages of 5 children born at the intervals of 3 years each is 50 years. What is the age of the youngest child?\",\"details\":\" \",\"datetime\":\"1439099443\",\"answered\":\"1\",\"vote\":\"0\",\"answers\":[{\"id\":\"884\",\"author\":\"788\",\"answer\":\"4 years\",\"datetime\":\"1439165670\",\"votes\":\"0\"}]}]"`

Comment: Show json data to find error

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON string represents JSON array instead of a JSON object. Using JSON.NET (I don't have the dev environment to test in UWP) I got the same error by doing `JObject.Parse(feed_data)`, and it can be fixed by using `JArray.Parse(feed_data)`. So, I strongly suspect that in UWP, the equivalent solution would be using [`JsonArray.Parse()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.data.json.jsonarray.parse.aspx) :

```
JsonArray arr = JsonArray.Parse(feed_data);
```